# Blazor WASM could not start debugging problem

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022, blazor-webassembly

My blazor wasm project was working properly until I installed new windows and new visual studio 2022.
No blazor wasm project can start debugging even the new created project (except when I uncheck the box ASP.Net Core Hosted).
[image]

When I want to start debugging this error appears:
[image: Error message]

I added IIS windows features, but still not working.
Now, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Make sure that the updated `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server` package version is compatible with the other packages and the .NET version you're targeting.Review the changes in the `Program.cs` file to identify any breaking changes introduced by the package update. The update might require some code changes.Clear your NuGet cache by using the `dotnet nuget locals all --clear` command in the terminal.Try to clean and rebuild the entire solution. Make sure you have the correct .NET SDKs installed for your project. share the error message you are getting from the Program.cs file.